# Moving old SSD into a new computer

Tags: 16.04, ssd

My laptop died and I have some important files on it.

Can I move the old SSD into the new computer and run with it?

Can I make it work with the Ubuntu Live and install the grub on it?

Or can I use the Ubuntu Live to access the files, save them and then format the SSD to install everything again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes and yes.

Any of these options will work out of the box. Except that maybe you will need to remove the proprietary drivers of the old computer.

Unless of course your disk is encrypted.

Comment: I have my disk encrypted. Will be this a problem?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry :( I guess not, because you move it "whole", but I am not sure what kind of encryption did you use (it might be hardware related and so undecryptable on other hardware).